# Extract multiple instances of text between two words inclusive of starting word but exclusive of ending word

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

A **PDB** file contains numerous paragraphs of conformations of a protein.

Each conformation starts with the keyword *ATOM* and ends with keyword *END*.

I am trying to read the file in bash such that I read every line from ATOM until END, but I don't want to read the word END.

I want to do this for each conformations (paragraphs) and store each paragraph in an array.

The file somewhat looks like this:

```
ATOM line 1...

ATOM line 2...

ATOM line 3...

# More lines....

END

ATOM line 1...

ATOM line 2...

ATOM line 3...

# more lines...

END
```

An ***ATOM*** to ***END*** is one conformation.

I want to be able to read each conformation into an array, **including the ATOM but excluding the END**.

I can do read text between two keywords exclusive of both the words, but I don't know how to include the starting word, but exclude the end word.

Also reading each conformation into an array such that `conf[0]` = first conformation , `conf[1]` = second conformation so on and so forth doesn't work.

### Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='coor.pdb'
echo Start
i=0
while read line; do
    conf[$i]=$(sed -n '/ATOM/,/END/{//!p}') 
    i=i+1           
done < $filename
echo $conf[0] > first_frame.data
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='coor.pdb'
echo Start
i=1
input=false
while read -r line
do
    if [ "${line%% *}" == "ATOM" ]
    then
        input=true
    elif [ "${line%% *}" == "END" ]
    then
        ((i++))                 # increase variable i by 1 == (i+1)
        rm -f "${i}_frame.data" # remove ${i}_frame.data" if exist
        input=false             # stop output lines until next ATOM
    fi
    if $input                   # if var INPUT is true add line to ${i}_frame.data file
    then
        echo "$line" >> "${i}_frame.data"
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

For future some **sed** hints:

```
sed '/ATOM/,/END/!d;/END/d'
sed -n '/ATOM/{:;N;s/\nEND//;T;p}'
```

So you can do task:

```
nl -s'.frame.data' -b p"^END" coor.pdb | 
sed -n '/ATOM/{s/^/echo \"/;:;s/ \{6,\}//;N;s/END//;T;s/\n  */\">/p}' |
bash
```

Comment: Oh! thank you so very much for your prompt reply @Costas. Can I please trouble you more to explain each line from the 2nd elif/then?

Comment: @shay: be aware that text processing in pure bash is quite slow compared to something like `awk`.  The shell's `read` builtin has to read one character at a time.

Comment: @Costas: you should quote `"${line%% *}"` if you're going to use it inside single `[` rather than `[[`, so the shell doesn't try to glob-expand it, or process any other metacharacters.  (I know word-splitting isn't a problem in this special-case, because you're already stripping off ` *`... unless there's a tab instead of space.)

Comment: @PeterCordes And even inside `[[ … ]]`, you need quotes if the variable expansion appears on the right-hand side of `==` or `!=` or `=~` and you want the value of the variable to be interpreted as a string rather than a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Text processing in bash is slow.  Pure-bash string manipulation is good for text you already have in variables, or for reading very small files.  I suspect computational biology files won't usually be small, so use a tool like `awk` that has a small startup cost, but processes text much more quickly than bash.

Assuming you really just want to split your `pdb` file:

```
awk -v RS='\nEND\n' '{ fn="frame" NR ".pdb"; print > fn; close(fn) }' "$filename"
```

Get awk to use `\nEND\n` as the input record separator, instead of newline, then you can even use its record counter.  The output record separator is still the default `ORS="\n"`.  (very nice suggestion by Costas.  I tweaked it so `END` has to be at the start of a line, and added `close` to make sure it doesn't use a ton of file-descriptors on inputs with very many conformations.)

My original idea was:

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0; fn="frame0.pdb"}
     !/^END/ { print > fn; }
     /^END/{ close(fn); fn="frame" ++i ".pdb"; }' \
     "$filename"
```

awk caches file-handles, so multiple `print > fn` don't result in close-reopen of the file.  (`close(fn)` does that.  It's there just for efficiency, so awk doesn't end up with boatloads of open files.)

The logic is: print every full line to the current filename.  When you see an `END` line, move on to the next filename.  If there isn't another line after the last `END`, then the new filename will never be written, and no vestigial last file will be created.

OTOH, if you want to do something with an array of line-blocks in memory:

```
# add a `!/^END/` condition to the concat block if you want to avoid a stray newline after each END
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}  
     !/^END/ { arr[i] = arr[i] $0 "\n"; }  # concat onto this array element
     /^END/ { i++; }
     END{for (k in arr) { print arr[k]; > ("frame" k ".pdb") } }' \
"$filename"
```

Then you have an awk array of lines to do with as you please in the `END` block.  It has good regex functions.

---

Failed attempt at bash driving sed (nvm, fails because `sed` doesn't read one-byte-at-a-time the way shell `read` does):

```
i=0
while true; do
    outf="frame${i}.data";
    ##### DON'T USE THIS, sed READS TOO MUCH #####
    strace -o sed.tr sed '/^END/q42' > "$outf";  # strace to see that the 2nd sed invocation finds the file empty
    ret=$?;
    ((i++));
    if [[ $ret == 0 ]];then  # sed didn't see END before EOF
        [[ -s $outf ]] || rm -f "$outf";  # clean up empty last file
        break;
    elif [[ $ret != 42 ]]; then
        echo some other sed error;
        break;
    fi;
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: If you wants just split use **R**ow**S**eparator `awk -v RS='END\n' '{print > NR ".frame.data"}'`

Comment: @Costas: well spotted that there's a solution that simple!  I tweaked that a bit and put it as the first suggestion in my answer.

Comment: OP don't want to have *END* included…